# How to initialize a huge sparse matrix in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, svd

I need to solve SVD for huge sparse matrix of dimension 1300000*1400000 in C++. While searching I found a library called redsvd. However I have search the way I use redsvd in visual studio 2010, I found this solution https://github.com/hoonto/redsvdwin but i could not know how to do so.
Then, I tried this

```
    typedef Eigen::Triplet<float> T;
    std::vector<T> tripletList;
    for(...)
    {
      // ...
      tripletList.push_back(T(i,j,v_ij));
    }
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>mat(rows,cols);
    mat.setFromTriplets(tripletList.begin(), tripletList.end());
```

but also it doesen't work because of the dimension of my matrix.
Can anyone suggest a solution for this issue?

Comment: Make a smaller matrix or buy a super computer.  The art of programming is to break issues down into smaller issues - and repeat until you have a whole load of small problems.  Your massive matrix is a big problem, don't try to solve it head on

Comment: How exactly does this fail with Eigen? Does it fail to compile, or does it fail to work correctly at run-time, and in either case what error message or unexpected output do you receive?

Comment: Yes please, explain how it fails! Also note that redsvd is a randomized algorithm, so you will only get an approximate result.

Comment: When I compiled the code, the running took more than 3 days than a message appears to Abort

Comment: No problem, I can continue my work with the n largest singular values @ggael

Comment: Is your question (only) about initializing the matrix, or about computing the SVD of a big matrix?

Comment: I need to solve these two issues... But first i have to initialize this matrix in my code @chtz

Comment: What is your hardware and how sparse is the matrix? Do you know the approximate number of total non zero elements in the matrix? And where did your program abort?

Comment: I have at most 30 non-zero elements in each row.I got  the core i7-6700HQ CPU and 16 GB Ram @Shadow

Comment: Ok, for a Laptop not bad but it is of course not really made for expensive computing stuff. But the initialization should be really no problem (if there is not that much computing to do for every matrix entry). Are you sure it fails still in the initialization process? (3 days for initialization!?) And are you doing other stuff or is the program the only process running? And do you use parallelization with openmp or similar?

Comment: No, in the code I am trying to construct a phylogenetic tree before the initialization of the matrix. This matrix will give a value of 1 if j is an ancestor of i. However, before the initialization, i could divide the data between nodes and leaves and i could calculate the height of the tree. This process took around 5 hours of compilation. After initialization, it is taking around 3 days and it stops.@Shadow

Comment: Make sure you compiled with compiler optimlization ON (aka "release mode" or -O3), then try to identify which step is taking so long between the push_backs to the std::vector and the  call to `setFromTriplets`.

Comment: Also, I see you are using a pretty old compiler, upgrading it might make a significant difference for c++ code.

Comment: 30 non zero elements / row = 42million elements.  Each being a float, you get 168 MB required to store the data; you then need 4 times that because you're putting the values into a vector and then copying into the matrix - still easily in range of your 16G.  It's also not something that should take a day to allocate - even if you're not reserving the size in the vector.

Have you confirmed where the massive delay is?  What you've posted doesn't match up with the time you said it should take; leading me to believe that your issue is actually in the "..." section, and not the sparceMatrix.

Comment: I tried a simple example to initialize this matrix: for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
 {
  for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
  {
    if (i%11== 0&& j%7==0)
    {
      tripletList.push_back(T(i, j, 1));
    }
  } but also the program abort..